# Compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u_m(x) u_n(x) |x|^r dx$ with $u_n$ hermite function.

Tags: definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds, hermite-polynomials

I would like to compute (or estimate) this integral of 2D Hermite function, where $n, m \in \mathbb{N}^2$ and $r \in [0, 2]$ :
$$I_{n, m}(r) := \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u_m(x) u_n(x) |x|^r dx$$
where, for $n = (n_1,n_2) \in \mathbb{N}^2$, and $x = (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ :
$$u_n(x) = (\pi n_1! n_2! 2^{n_1} 2^{n_2})^{-1/2} H_{n_1}(x_1) H_{n_2}(x_2) e^{-\frac12 (x_1^2 + x_2^2)}$$
and for $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $H_k(y)$ is the Hermite polynomial defined by :
$$H_{k}(y) = (-1)^{k} e^{y^2} \dfrac{d^k}{dy^k} e^{-y^2}$$
Finally, for  $x = (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $|x|^r = (|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2)^{r/2}$.

By parity argument, $I_{n, m}(r) = 0$ when :

1. $n_1$ is even and $n_2$ is odd / $n_2$ is even and $n_1$ is odd
2. $m_1$ is even and $m_2$ is odd / $m_2$ is even and $m_1$ is odd

But, I would like to understand what happend for the other case.

According to the equation (52) of this page https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html, there is a closed form for a related integral for the 1D case and integer $r$.

I suspect that there is no closed form for the non integer case in the 1D and 2D settings, but an upper bound of $I_{n, m}(r)$ is ok for me.

QUESTION : How to upper bound $|I_{n, m}(r)|$ for $r \in (0, 2]$ ?

I am not used to Hermite function, and I don't know wich properties of theses function could be useful, so I don't know how to start. Do you have any hint or reference ?

CONTEXT : I came across with integral in a signal processing problem. I the best world, I hope that $I_{n,m}(r)$ is "small".

EDIT :

Using the fact that $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^2}$ is an hermitian basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, I was able to obtain that, $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}^2, I_{n, m} \underset{|n| \to \infty}{\to} 0$. Indeed the function $u_m(x)|x|^r \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and thus $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^2} \Big|\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u_n(x) u_m(x)|x|^r dx\Big|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |u_m(x)|^2 |x|^{2r} dx < \infty$.

But, I am interested in the speed of decreasing of $I_{n, m}(r)$ as $|n|, |m| \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For $r=0$ there is no problem because this is just an integral over decoupled Cartesian Gaussians,
so the integral is a product of integrals. Otherwise, omitting the unrelated constants,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy
 H_{n_1}(x)H_{n_2}(y)e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}
H_{m_1}(x)H_{m_2}(y)e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}
(x^2+y^2)^{r/2}
$$
$$
=
\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi
\int_0^{\infty}\rho d\rho
 H_{n_1}(\rho\cos\phi)H_{n_2}(\rho\sin\phi)e^{-\rho^2}
H_{m_1}(\rho\cos\phi)H_{m_2}(\rho\sin\phi)
\rho^r
$$
$$
=
\sum_{l_1=0}^{\lfloor n_1/2\rfloor}
\sum_{l_2=0}^{\lfloor n_2/2\rfloor}
\sum_{s_1=0}^{\lfloor m_1/2\rfloor}
\sum_{s_2=0}^{\lfloor m_2/2\rfloor}
\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi
\int_0^{\infty}\rho d\rho
n_1!\frac{(-)^{l_1}}{l_1!(n_1-2l_1)!}(2\rho\cos\phi)^{n_1-2l_1}
$$
$$
\times
n_2!\frac{(-)^{l_2}}{l_2!(n_2-2l_2)!}(2\rho\sin\phi)^{n_2-2l_2}
$$
$$
\times
m_1!\frac{(-)^{s_1}}{s_1!(m_1-2s_1)!}(2\rho\cos\phi)^{m_1-2s_1}
$$
$$
\times
m_2!\frac{(-)^{s_2}}{s_2!(m_2-2s_2)!}(2\rho\sin\phi)^{m_2-2s_2}
e^{-\rho^2}
\rho^r
$$
Define $R_n\equiv \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x^2}=\frac12\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})$
$$
\ldots =
\sum_{l_1=0}^{\lfloor n_1/2\rfloor}
\sum_{l_2=0}^{\lfloor n_2/2\rfloor}
\sum_{s_1=0}^{\lfloor m_1/2\rfloor}
\sum_{s_2=0}^{\lfloor m_2/2\rfloor}
R_{1+r+n_1-2l_1+n_2-2l_2+m_1-2s_1+m_2-2s_2}
$$
$$
\times \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi
n_1!\frac{(-)^{l_1}}{l_1!(n_1-2l_1)!}(2\cos\phi)^{n_1-2l_1}
$$
$$
\times
n_2!\frac{(-)^{l_2}}{l_2!(n_2-2l_2)!}(2\sin\phi)^{n_2-2l_2}
$$
$$
\times
m_1!\frac{(-)^{s_1}}{s_1!(m_1-2s_1)!}(2\cos\phi)^{m_1-2s_1}
$$
$$
\times
m_2!\frac{(-)^{s_2}}{s_2!(m_2-2s_2)!}(2\sin\phi)^{m_2-2s_2}
$$
$$
\ldots =
\sum_{l_1=0}^{\lfloor n_1/2\rfloor}
\sum_{l_2=0}^{\lfloor n_2/2\rfloor}
\sum_{s_1=0}^{\lfloor m_1/2\rfloor}
\sum_{s_2=0}^{\lfloor m_2/2\rfloor}
R_{1+r+n_1-2l_1+n_2-2l_2+m_1-2s_1+m_2-2s_2}
$$
$$
\times P(n_2-2l_2+m_2-2s_2,n_1-2l_1+m_1-2l_2)
n_1!\frac{(-)^{l_1}}{l_1!(n_1-2l_1)!}(2)^{n_1-2l_1}
\times
n_2!\frac{(-)^{l_2}}{l_2!(n_2-2l_2)!}(2)^{n_2-2l_2}
$$
$$
\times
m_1!\frac{(-)^{s_1}}{s_1!(m_1-2s_1)!}(2)^{m_1-2s_1}
\times
m_2!\frac{(-)^{s_2}}{s_2!(m_2-2s_2)!}(2)^{m_2-2s_2}.
$$
This uses the shortcut
$$
P(p,q)\equiv \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
=
\int_0^{\pi} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
$$
$$
=
\int_0^{\pi} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
-(-)^p \int_{\pi}^{0} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
=
\int_0^{\pi} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
+(-)^p \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
$$
so $P(p,q)=0$ if $p$ is odd. For $p$ even
$$
P(p,q)
=
2\int_0^{\pi} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
=
2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
+2\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
$$
$$
=
2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
-2(-)^q \int_{\pi/2}^{0} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
=
2\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
+2(-)^q \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
$$
so $P(p,q)=0$ if $q$ is odd. So if $p$ and $q$ are even
$$
P(p,q)=
4\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^q\phi \sin^p\phi d\phi
=
\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{(p+q)(p+q-2}P(p-2,q-2)
$$
recursively starting at $P(0,0)=2\pi$, $P(0,2k)=P(2k,0)=2\pi \frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!}$ where $!!$ is the double factorial. For $r=1$ one can use the Maple
program

```
r := 1:
for nsum from 0 to 12 do
    # need 4 weak compositions so nsum+4 to partition
    for pnsum in combinat[partition](nsum+4) do
        if nops(pnsum) = 4 then
            n1 := pnsum[1]-1 ;
            n2 := pnsum[2]-1 ;
            m1 := pnsum[3]-1 ;
            m2 := pnsum[4]-1 ;
            Hn1 := n1!*add( (-1)^l1/l1!/(n1-2*l1)!*(2*rho*cos(phi))^(n1-2*l1),l1=0..floor(n1/2)) ;
            Hn2 := n2!*add( (-1)^l2/l2!/(n2-2*l2)!*(2*rho*sin(phi))^(n2-2*l2),l2=0..floor(n2/2)) ;
            Hm1 := m1!*add( (-1)^s1/s1!/(m1-2*s1)!*(2*rho*cos(phi))^(m1-2*s1),s1=0..floor(m1/2)) ;
            Hm2 := m2!*add( (-1)^s2/s2!/(m2-2*s2)!*(2*rho*sin(phi))^(m2-2*s2),s2=0..floor(m2/2)) ;
            # this rho from (x1^2+x2^2)^(r/2)
            Hn1*Hn2*Hm1*Hm2*exp(-rho^2)*rho ;
            # this from jacobian
            %*rho ;
            expand(%) ;
            int(%,phi=0..2*Pi) ;
            int(%,rho=0..infinity) ;
            %/sqrt(Pi*n1!*n2!*2^(n1+n2)) ;
            %/sqrt(Pi*m1!*m2!*2^(m1+m2)) ;
            Inm := % ;
            if Inm <> 0 then
                print(n1,n2,m1,m2,simplify(Inm),evalf(Inm)) ;
            end if;
        end if ;
    end do:
end do:
```

which generates the following table of $n_1$, $n_2$, $m_1$, $m_2$, $I_{n,m}$ (analytic and floating point)

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2*Pi^(1/2), .8862269255
0, 0, 0, 2, 1/8*2^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .3133285342
1, 1, 1, 1, 15/16*Pi^(1/2), 1.661675485
0, 0, 2, 2, -1/32*Pi^(1/2), -.5538918284e-1
0, 0, 0, 4, -1/64*6^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.6783761762e-1
0, 2, 2, 2, 11/128*2^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .2154133673
1, 1, 1, 3, 5/64*6^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .3391880881
0, 1, 2, 3, -1/64*Pi^(1/2)*3^(1/2), -.4796843943e-1
0, 0, 2, 4, 1/128*3^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .2398421973e-1
0, 0, 0, 6, 1/128*5^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .3096349451e-1
2, 2, 2, 2, 1235/1024*Pi^(1/2), 2.137676276
1, 1, 3, 3, -15/512*Pi^(1/2), -.5192735892e-1
0, 2, 2, 4, -25/2048*Pi^(1/2)*2^(1/2)*3^(1/2), -.5299813876e-1
0, 0, 4, 4, -15/2048*Pi^(1/2), -.1298183973e-1
1, 1, 1, 5, -5/1024*30^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.4740297638e-1
0, 1, 2, 5, 3/1024*Pi^(1/2)*15^(1/2), .2011137962e-1
0, 0, 2, 6, -5/2048*10^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.1368406059e-1
0, 0, 0, 8, -5/4096*70^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.1810231062e-1
1, 3, 3, 3, 135/2048*6^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .2861899494
2, 2, 2, 4, 529/4096*3^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .3964891323
1, 2, 3, 4, -93/4096*2^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.5691319078e-1
0, 2, 4, 4, 57/8192*2^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .1744113911e-1
1, 1, 3, 5, 9/2048*5^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .1741696566e-1
0, 1, 4, 5, -9/4096*5^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.8708482825e-2
0, 2, 2, 6, 25/4096*Pi^(1/2)*5^(1/2), .2419023008e-1
0, 0, 4, 6, 7/8192*30^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .8295520867e-2
1, 1, 1, 7, 3/2048*35^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .1536031991e-1
0, 1, 2, 7, -3/4096*Pi^(1/2)*2^(1/2)*35^(1/2), -.1086138637e-1
0, 0, 2, 8, 7/8192*35^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .8960186613e-2
0, 0, 0, 10, 21/8192*7^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .1202135182e-1
3, 3, 3, 3, 11715/8192*Pi^(1/2), 2.534704207
2, 2, 4, 4, -1191/32768*Pi^(1/2), -.6442237966e-1
0, 4, 4, 4, -351/65536*6^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.2325293339e-1
1, 3, 3, 5, -99/16384*Pi^(1/2)*6^(1/2)*5^(1/2), -.5866118327e-1
0, 3, 4, 5, 49/32768*Pi^(1/2)*3^(1/2)*10^(1/2), .1451716152e-1
1, 1, 5, 5, -75/16384*Pi^(1/2), -.8113649831e-2
2, 2, 2, 6, -313/32768*10^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.5353888704e-1
1, 2, 3, 6, 49/16384*15^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), .2053036670e-1
0, 2, 4, 6, -51/32768*Pi^(1/2)*15^(1/2), -.1068417043e-1
0, 0, 6, 6, -105/32768*Pi^(1/2), -.5679554881e-2
1, 1, 3, 7, -5/16384*210^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.7838530434e-2
0, 1, 4, 7, 7/32768*Pi^(1/2)*2^(1/2)*105^(1/2), .5486971303e-2
0, 2, 2, 8, -61/65536*Pi^(1/2)*2^(1/2)*35^(1/2), -.1380301185e-1
0, 0, 4, 8, -21/65536*105^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.5819811925e-2
1, 1, 1, 9, -15/32768*70^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.6788366483e-2
0, 1, 2, 9, 21/32768*Pi^(1/2)*35^(1/2), .6720139959e-2
0, 0, 2, 10, -63/65536*14^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.6375284543e-2
0, 0, 0, 12, -21/65536*231^(1/2)*Pi^(1/2), -.8632176075e-2
```

where only cases for $I_{n,m}\neq 0$, $n_1+n_2+m_1+m_2\le 12$, $n_1\le n_2\le m_1\le m_2$ have been tabulated.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to use the explicit expression of $H_m$ and polar coordinates. But it seems quite hard to get an upper bound of the last quantity.

Comment: It's for example obvious that $P(0,0)=2\pi$, $P(2,2)=\pi/4$, $P(2,4)=P(4,2)=\pi/8$ and all other P(n,m) are smaller. Similarly for R (a multiple of sqrt(Pi)) there is an upper bound based on its maximum argument.

Comment: I agree but doing this we will lose all the cancelations of the signs $(-1)^{n}$. I suspect that the obtained bound will be really big.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts and for the numerical simulations. But I need a theoretical bound that I can use in calculus. Something like $|I_{n, m}(r) \lesssim |n-m|^{-1/r}$.